# GWT can't be found in intellij 12

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, debian

I have installed [IntelliJ 12.1.6](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) Community Edition and I'm trying to follow all of the tutorials they have for setting up GWT with it, but the GWT options for enabling and setting the GWT-SDK classpath is nowhere to be found in the settings.

I tried the following:

- Enabling the GWT plugin from Settings -> plugins, but there is no such entry there.
- Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S and go to Facets, and select GWT, but GWT is not there.
- Trying to add GWT from the Module Settings, but it's not there either.

Is there something trivial that I'm missing?
I run oracle 7 jdk with debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GWT Plugin is not part of the Community Edition.

Here some stuff, how to enable GWT in the Community Edition. Hope that helps:
http://java.dzone.com/tips/gwt-development-intellij-idea

Comment: That's bad, here is the comparison chart(where it says that it's not supported) if anybody else has the same problem:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Answer (score 1):

It should be in your project settings, not intellij settings.

Add a new module:
Project Structure -> Modules -> Add GWT

Set installation path:
Project Structure -> Facets -> GWT

If GWT is not listed in the "+" dropdown, then probably reinstall the gwt support plugin.

Comment: Nope, I don't use Maven, only pure GWT.
I thought the gwt support plugin was installed by default?
As it says here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gwt.html that it is natively supported.

Comment: Wrong, the GWT Plugin is not part of the Community Edition. It is there by default in the Ultimate Edition.